# Problem installing amdgpu pro 16.60 for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amd-graphics

I've already installed amdgpu-pro 16.60 for ubuntu 16.04 from its official website. But the problem begins after installation, when I tried to reboot, the monitor sleeps, but the system is on. I could enter TTY but, still the monitor sleeps.

Am I missing something?

note : I am using ubuntustudio 16.04.2 (xenial), some informations:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics]
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics]
 Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XTX [Radeon R7 260X/360]
Subsystem: Hightech Information System Ltd. Bonaire XTX [Radeon R7 260X/360]
Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Comment: Same issue here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/880011/screen-stays-blank-after-few-reboots-overclocked-system-with-16-04