# AMD-GPU on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xorg, radeon, gpu-driver

I have AMD A10-7870K CPU with R7 GPU. I have setup the system to use amdgpu instead of radeon. The kernel module is loaded properly. I blacklisted radeon module by putting 'blacklist radeon' into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf` and added 'amdgpu' into `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`. Then ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Yet, the `radeon` module keeps getting loaded and I don't know why...

```
root@ubuntu:~# lsmod |grep -e radeon -e amdgpu
amdgpu                987136  0
radeon               1515520  3
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
ttm                    94208  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        155648  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm                   364544  7 ttm,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon
root@ubuntu:~#
```

At `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf` I have

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMD"
    Driver "amdgpu"
EndSection
```

However at `Xorg.0.log` I see:

```
[    17.774] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    17.774] (EE) AMDGPU(0): amdgpu_device_initialize failed
[    17.774] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    17.774] (EE) AMDGPU(G0): amdgpu_device_initialize failed
[    17.774] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    17.774] (EE) AMDGPU(1): amdgpu_device_initialize failed
[    17.774] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    17.775] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    17.775] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    17.775] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    17.775] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
```

So the questions are:

1. Isn't this suppose to work on this processor? I read the AMDGPU driver supports Sea Islands GCN GPU.
2. The system is working seemingly fine. X is starting and working. How can I check which graphics driver X is using?
3. How do I fix the amdpgu_device_initialize failed messages?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

According to user experiences A10-7870K should work fine with AMDGPU-PRO
https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/amd-linux/873464-amdgpu-pro-beta-2-driver-is-playing-nicely-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-the-r9-fury?p=874788#post874788
Not that I could install it, it gives some dependency errors. I think it may help if I can install amdgpu-pro but it seems impossible! The error below is from `amdgpu-pro-16.60-379184`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-pro : Depends: libvdpau-amdgpu-pro but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: clinfo-amdgpu-pro but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-pro-dkms : Depends: dkms (>= 1.95) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-pro-amdgpu1:i386
                    Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:i386
                    Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386
                    Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386
                    Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386
                    Depends: vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386
                    Depends: libvdpau-amdgpu-pro:i386
                    Depends: libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:i386
                    Depends: opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now I have also made a question at AMD forums for this driver installation failure:
https://community.amd.com/message/2784212

Comment: Just keep in mind that AMD graphics drivers are a *mess* in 16.04+.

Comment: @AndroidDev No they aren't. You just can't use fglrx in newer kernel and Xorg versions.

Comment: I don't think _amdgpu_ supports integrated graphics in the APUs, but only discrete cards, for the time being, at least, based on https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: That is for amdgpu-pro but I already found some forum entries where people said they got amdgpu-pro working with my processor (updated my post). I would like to install amdgpu-pro drivers but I am getting dependency erros. I don't understand how other people are installing them!

Comment: @dobey If they weren't a mess, then they'd work just fine OOTB like Nouveau does...

Comment: @AndroidDev, I think that radeon/amdgpu works as good as nouveau. I am now using the machine with kodi just fine even with things like vdpau support. To be fair, the problems as mostly fault of Linux. In the past, I had same problems with both nvidia and amd cards almost every time when there was a Linux kernel update. But I never had problems with Windows updates. Anyway, the problem is that I want to use AMDGPU or PRO version and be able to confirm that they work. I think I am missing something simple somewhere... :(

Comment: @AndroidDev They work fine OOTB for most cases, just like Nouveau does. None of these three drivers supports all features of every card, or even every card, by the respective manufacturers.

Comment: @AndroidDev also nouveau does not support a bunch of features or support badly on different cards. Maybe I misunderstood your reply. Nouveau does not support things like SLI or CUDA on any card for example -> https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I solved the issue with the AMDGPU-PRO driver installation (problem was Ubuntu after all). I am guessing the open source AMDGPU does not support my GPU. In either case, it looks like AMD did a great job with this new driver. Once I fixed the problem in Ubuntu, it installed easily and was working right away. Thank you all for your responses!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with fresh install. Try adding the i386 architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then try the setup again.

Comment: This was my issue, very used to x86... tripped me up back on a pentium

Comment: This worked like a charm on my clean installation of Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 amd64!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the AMDGPU-PRO installation problem. Caused by Linux/Ubuntu after all ( and people keep blaming AMD for every problem :p ). When I updated from 14.04 to 16.04, the upgrade process seem to have left some old GCC packages behind and they were causing the problem.

I traced what `apt-get` does by using `apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install libc6:i386`

After I saw some 14.04 references in the output. I found out that updater left some GCC stuff behind from 14.04

```
# dpkg -l |grep 14.04
ii  gcc-6-base:amd64                      6.2.0-3ubuntu11~14.04                    amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc1:amd64                         1:6.2.0-3ubuntu11~14.04                  amd64        GCC support library
rc  libmysqlclient18:amd64                5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                  amd64        MySQL database client library
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-43-generic         3.19.0-43.49~14.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-43-generic   3.19.0-43.49~14.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  postgresql-9.3                        9.3.16-0ubuntu0.14.04                    amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.3 server
ii  postgresql-client-9.3                 9.3.16-0ubuntu0.14.04                    amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.3
ii  postgresql-doc-9.3                    9.3.16-0ubuntu0.14.04                    all          documentation for the PostgreSQL database management system
ii  ubuntu-mono                           14.04+16.04.20161024-0ubuntu1            all          Ubuntu Mono Icon theme
#
```

I had to download the xenial versions from here:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/gcc-6-base/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libgcc1/download
```

Then it was just a matter of uninstalling old 14.04 versions and installing 16.04 versions

```
# dpkg --force-depends -r libgcc1 gcc-6-base
# dpkg -i gcc-6-base_6.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
# dpkg -i libgcc1_6.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

AMDGPU-PRO installer was able to install packages properly. I hope this helps to somebody who finds this post! I found some other threads in forums where people had similar problems.

Now, the `radeon` module is not loaded anymore, only `amdgpu` module is loaded. I was getting 300fps earlier with glxgears and it is 5000+fps (it may be low because I underclocked the internal gpu but shows things are working). Clinfo finds the GPU, so OpenCL is working.

I had to keep /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf which had `blacklist radeon` line. But I didn't need `amdgpu` line in /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

Now `glxinfo` shows AMD.

```
server glx vendor string: AMD
...
client glx vendor string: AMD
...
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Graphics
```

Before xorg log showed:

```
[ 67077.690] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 67077.690] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: radeonsi
[ 67077.690] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: radeonsi
```

Now Xorg log shows:

```
[    26.113] (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    26.113] (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: amdgpu
[    26.113] (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: amdgpu
```

No more `AMDGPU(0): amdgpu_device_initialize failed` error messages.

While I could not get the open source AMDGPU driver work, perhaps it was because the open source driver did not support my GPU. I am happy now that the AMD's driver is supporting it and everything is working. So I will consider this issue closed.

Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: Thinking whether your answer would be relevant to 16.04 fresh installation. Even fresh installation of 16.04 also have this problem.

Comment: What problem exactly? Did you make a question? Post it's link please.

Comment: Here is the question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/880011/screen-stays-blank-after-few-reboots-overclocked-system-with-16-04-amd-gpu

The issue is there whether I overclock or not.

Comment: Your issue seems to be totally unrelated :)

Comment: the fps you mention of 300 seems to be with vsync turned on. Try again with command: `vblank_mode=0 glxgears`

Comment: That is not the problem, my display is 60hz anyway, not 300hz. I could see in glxinfo that software rendering was used.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `blacklist radeon` you have to add it to the conf file and then issue the command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I did that of course, it was implied. I just forgot to write that I did that...

Comment: OK, just for reference

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or need the i386 architecture, it can be fixed by skipping these packages alltogether. Simply download the latest driver, and run it's installer:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install
```

This will give you the 'unmet dependencies' error, but will set the apt repository. Now you can manually install the amd64 packages (omit `vulkan-amdgpu-pro` for versions <18.20):

```
sudo apt install amdgpu amdgpu-pro vulkan-amdgpu-pro
```